# umask's full path and runing it as different user

Tags: bash, umask

Today i learned about the command `umask` and it returns `0002` for my default user.

I wanted to see its value for the root user, so I executed `sudo umask` and it returns:

```bash
$ sudo umask
sudo: umask: command not found
```

Thinking that it was a `PATH` issue, I tried locating the "binary" of `umask` using `which umask`, but it does not return anything.

I can still get the root's umask value by connecting to a shell, *then* running it:

```bash
$ sudo su
# umask
0022
```

Why doesn't the full path of umask's binary show up? Is it because it's a system call? Why can't I sudo it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`umask` is not a binary file, actually it's a shell built-in, so you need a shell owned by a user be able to run it.

```
$ type umask
umask is a shell builtin
```

Comment: So it's a shell built-in, same as `bind` and `pwd`? I can run `sudo pwd` and `which pwd` successfully though. What are the differences?

Comment: `sudo sh -c umask` or `sudo -u user sh -c umask`

Comment: @bac0n thank you! So I guess this is just a matter of the terminal and is not really that interesting

Comment: @AnasTiour Some programs like `pwd` for compatibly purposes also have a binary version.